# Module vs. (partial) Class? Passing information from main form to functions in modules?

Tags: vb.net

So I just started working with visual basic on a aerodynamic calculation software from my university. There were a few people working on it before me and as they all are were amateurs (including me) with programming the software ended up having everything - including even the most complex mathematic calculations - coded in the main class (form1). Coming with some amateur experience from other languages like java I try to clean things up and get back to OOP.

Long story short:
For the sake of structure and clarity for future programmers I try to group functions and subs. Ive read that a module would be the euqivalent to a static class in java, but I am facing one major problem:

[image: ErrorMessage]

```vb
Module module1
    Public Sub testfunction()
        trView1.Nodes.Add("Test1")
        cmbBox1.Items.Add("Test2")
    End Sub
End Module
```

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btn2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
        module1.testfunction()

        trView1.Nodes.Add("Test1")
        cmbBox1.Items.Add("Test2")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Inside a module can not access any buttons, comboBoxes, TreeViews etc. from the main form designer. Buttons are okay as I can acess them in the main and just execute functions from the module, but I do need to work with some boxes, Treeviews etc inside the modules functions. Without that, the sole purpose of a module strucuring the project in meaningful areas (e.g. module1_speedCalculations, module2_complexMatricesCalculations)

I even tried changing the protection level of the treeviews and comboboxes inside the form1.designer.vb-code to public but it did not seem to change anything.

For now I got it working with partial classes but I feel like that is not the way to group functions and subs.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any additional steep I keep missing, or am I entirely wrong working with modules?

Comment: It seems like the main issue is that everything is very tightly integrated with the UI.  If you want more general-purpose functions, they should take numeric, string, and/or boolean inputs that are derived from the states of the various controls.  These functions would then be suitable for putting into a module (if more procedural) or class (if more likely to be using instanced data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be breaking up the code in the wrong way.  Don't just cut/paste methods/etc. from one file to another *just to make the file smaller*.  Logically *separate the concerns*.

Interacting with form elements (buttons, text boxes, etc.) is UI logic.  It *belongs* on the form.

What *doesn't* belong on the form is logic unrelated to that interaction.  Business logic, calculations, infrastructure interactions (database, external services, etc.), and so on.

For example, let's assume you have a method which performs a calculation and displays the result on the form.  Something like:

```
Public Sub DisplaySomething()
    ' a bunch of logic and calculations happen here
    ' then at the end...
    textBox1.Text = someResult
End Sub
```

If you want to move this logic into a module, this `Sub` *as-is* can't be moved because it's coupled to the display logic.  But you can refactor the code to *return the result* instead of display it on the form:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    ' a bunch of logic and calculations happen here
    ' then at the end...
    Return someResult
End Sub
```

Then the logic on the form would simply invoke that method and display the result:

```
Public Sub DisplaySomething()
    textBox1.Text = SomeModule.DoSomething()
End Sub
```

Refactoring the code isn't just about moving pieces into new files.  It's about separating the concerns.  UI logic belongs in one place, business logic in another place, infrastructure integration logic in another place, etc.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I am not entirerly sure if that works for me. In terms of output like displaying an result or a text on the form I can definitely follow you. But I also need to get the data FROM the form, for instance the entire TreeView, which the number of nodes would then determine the first steps of my calculation function. And then I have to work with the information in the nodes iteself. But I might not be proficient enough with stuff like TreeViews in general to understand your assignment.

Comment: @Verolox: Any data that needs to be passed *to* the business logic would be passed as arguments/parameters to the method/function.  Overall the point is to de-couple the different concerns in the code.  In this case UI logic and business logic.  The act of performing the calculation is different from the act of gathering input or displaying output.  You can begin this refactoring by simply copying the logic as-is, as you've done. And then any UI-coupled code (anything directly referencing a UI element for example) is an opportunity to better define the inputs and outputs of the business logic.

Comment: @Verolox I'm sure that the TreeView is loaded from some data source? Pass that data source to the newly refactored functions. Don't treat the TreeView as a data store; treat it as a data display. Work with the underlying data source for data manipulation/calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the objects that you want to manipulate, to the gunction

like

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btn2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
        module1.testfunction(trView1,cmbBox1)

        trView1.Nodes.Add("Test1")
        cmbBox1.Items.Add("Test2")
    End Sub
End Class



Module module1
Public Sub testfunction(ByRef trView1 As TreeView, ByRef cmbBox1 As ComboBox)
    trView1.Nodes.Add("Text1")
    cmbBox1.Items.Add("text2")
End Sub
End Module
```

For a more dynamic approach, you can for example add the textes for both ui elements

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btn2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
        module1.testfunction(trView1,cmbBox1,"Test1")

        trView1.Nodes.Add("Test1")
        cmbBox1.Items.Add("Test2")
    End Sub
End Class

Module module1
    Public Sub testfunction(ByRef trView1 As TreeView, ByRef cmbBox1 As ComboBox, ByVal text1 As String, ByVal text2 As String)
        trView1.Nodes.Add(text1)
        cmbBox1.Items.Add(text2)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Good that you mention handing over parameters. I actually started doing that in the first place, but then came across and even worse problem: 
You have to understand that this software is pretty complex already. There are numerous Tabs and Pages, Buttons, Boxes, TreeViews etc. I probably had to hand over 10 or 20 parameters to make that work - for each function/sub.

Comment: and you cn add hundrets of parameters or thousands, you can add for every tab its own function, or add the tab to the function, also every tab has its own unique name, so the right combox and treeview would be selected